# How to build Modernizr with bower and brunch - missing main in bower.json

Tags: zurb-foundation, bower, modernizr, brunch

I've read this [github issue](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1334) stating:

> there isn't a main file to be in the main.

I have [modernizr 3.0.0](https://modernizr.com/) installed automatically as a dependency of [Foundation 5.5.2](http://foundation.zurb.com) and am trying to build my project with [Brunch](http://brunch.io).

When running `brunch build` I get the following error:

`Error: Component JSON file "/path/to/brunch-test/bower_components/modernizr/.bower.json" must have`main`property. See https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components#README`

So following the [read-components issue](https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components#README), I am trying to override modernizr's `main` in my root `bower.json` but not sure how to go about it as there's no simple compiled `modernizr.js` present.

I know modernizr is meant to be customized, and indeed the [modernizr 3 release news](https://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-3-new-release-site) state there is `a really cool solution of dynamically creating a custom package that can be installed via bower` but I'm unable to find information about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

So my directory tree is something along the lines of (simplified):

```
/
|-- bower.json
|-- bower_components
  |-- modernizr
    |-- bin
      |-- modernizr
```

I went into `bower_components/modernizr` and ran `npm install` to get the dependencies required to run the `bin/modernizr` builder.

Then I went to their website to pick out the features I required: https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses

Next, I clicked `Build` and downloaded the `Command Line Config` which I placed at the root directory of my project as `modernizr-config.json`.

Then I ran `bin/modernizr -c ../../modernizr-config.json` which placed a custom built `modernizr.js` in `/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js`

Finally, in my root `bower.json`, I added (following the [read components issue](https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components#README):

```
"overrides": {
  "modernizr": {
    "main": "modernizr.js"
  }
}
```

and `brunch build` is running beautifully now.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I thought by the statement they made, you would be able to use Bower exclusively, but having to manually build Modernizr beforehand adds unwanted complexity

Comment: Same here, hoped they'd have bower "on the go" support, but alas.